# How can I add a second bar label to my Google Sheets stacked bar chart?

Tags: charts, google-sheets, google-visualization

I'm currently working on replicating an Excel chart in Google Sheets and I can't figure out how to add the second criteria to the label of each bar without changing the cell data itself. The first picture is what it looks like now and the second is what I am trying to get it to look like.

[image: Current Bar Chart with label]

[image: Ideal bar chart with double label]